# Assumption check on proving a theorem

Tags: general-topology, advice

Let $\mathcal{B}=\{[a,b):a\in \Bbb R, b\in \Bbb Q,a<b\}$

$\mathcal{B}$ is the basis for a topology $\tau_{1}$ on $\Bbb R$.

The space $(\Bbb R,\tau_1)$ is called the
*Sorgenfrey line*

**Prove**
If $\tau$ is the Euclidean topology on $\Bbb R$ then $\tau_1 \supsetneq \tau$.

*Strategy*

If I can show the union of open sets of the
Sorgenfrey line is inside  $\tau$

If I can show the intersections of the
Sorgenfrey line is inside $\tau$

Then I think I have proved it

The empty set and $X$ are obvious.

Are my assumptions correct

If not what do l have to do?

Thanks

Comment: You know that the intervals of the form $(a,b)$ for $a,b\in\Bbb Q$ and $a<b$ are a base for the Euclidean topology. You can prove that $\tau\subseteq\tau_1$ by showing that each of these open intervals is a union of elements of $B$, and you can show that the inclusion is proper by showing, for instance, that $[0,1)\in\tau_1\setminus\tau$.

Comment: I corrected it. It is $\supset$ Is the meaning the same

Comment: So the intersection is superfluous

Comment: General theorem: if $\mathscr{B}$ is a base for a topology $\tau$ on a set $X$, and $\tau_1$ is a topology on $X$, then $\tau\subseteq\tau_1$ iff $\mathscr{B}\subseteq\tau_1$. Proving this does require looking at intersections and unions, but it’s very easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$[0,1) \in \mathcal{B}$ so $[0,1) \in \tau_1$, but $[0,1) \notin \tau$ as $0$ is not an interior point of $[0,1)$ in the Euccidean topology (any neighbourhood of $0$ contains some open interval $(-\varepsilon, \varepsilon)$, but such sets cannot be contained in $[0,1)$ as they always contain negative reals.)

Every basic open set $(a,b)$ ($a < b$) of $\tau_2$ is in $\tau_1$, as $$(a,b) = \bigcup \{[c,d)\mid c \in (a,b), d \in \Bbb Q, c < d < b\}$$
which is a union of sets from $\mathcal{B}$ so lies in $\tau_2$.

As all sets in $\tau$ are unions of these intervals, all Euclidean open sets are in $\tau_1$ and you'rre done showing the inclusion.

Comment: I showed the union of sets already. But the top part no. ,That is the missing element I needed Thanks

Comment: @Homer I gave the proof too.

Comment: Thanks.l am trying to rewrite it in my words. Morris states you can’t learn topology or math by reading other proofs. But what I am supposed to do when l chase my tail?